# Calculate the general average grade with sum group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

I have to display for each user the first and last name, year as studyYear, age, average grade, and also the general average grade.

General average grade I need to be computed like this:

`Sum(AverageGrade)/ total number of grades`

```
[userID]
[FirstName]
[LastName] 
[BirthDate] 
[Year] 
[AverageGrade]
```

My problem is the sum of the  the general average grade. I understand that I have to use `Sum(AverageGrade)` + `group by` but it wont work, help?

```
select FirstName+' '+LastName as FullName,
AverageGrade ,Year as StudyYear,
DATEDIFF(year,BirthDate,GETDATE())  AS AgeInYears
from Student
```

How do I include the `Sum(AverageGrade)` here? Or how do I rewrite?

```
  FirstName LastName   Year   AverageGrade  [GeneralAverageGrade]
 
  Fatima       Alo      2         9.20         7.45
  Omar       Kutum      1         5.88         7.45
  Sado      Kerkzm      3         7.20         7.45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want a grand average of column `averagegrade` over the whole dataset? If so, use window functions:

```
select s.*, avg(averagegrade) over() avg_averagegrade
from students s
```